# Keyword search in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am searching the facebook status which contains the specific keywords as follows.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=test&date_format=U&limit=60
   &access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

the above query returns the result correctly,

But when i search the keyword contains the space (ex: graph api). It doesn't returns the status which contains the keyword "graph api".

It returns the results of the keyword search graph and api seperately.

Is there any possible way to search the keywords which contains the space?

**Update:**

Methods which have been tried by me:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook+search&date_format=U&
      limit=60&access_token={{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}}

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook%20search&date_format=U&
     limit=60&access_token={{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}}

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook%20Bsearch&date_format=U&
    limit=60&access_token={{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}}

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="facebook search"&date_format=U&
    limit=60&  access_token={{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

the above all gave the same result.

Comment: What about a combination of using also the quotes and also the url encoded space?

Comment: Quotes with the encoded content gives empty results.

Comment: Any luck? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to try is taking your query and performing a URL encode on it. You can try these two options -

1. `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=graph+api&date_format=U&limit=60
   &access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
2. `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=graph%20api&date_format=U&limit=60
   &access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

These two options attempt to encode the space character in the query first with a `+` character, and then with `%20`. I'm fairly sure that one (or both) of these options will provide the results you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Lix, Thanx for your response. I already tried both of these methods which doesn't gives a proper response.(Although it is working for keyword "graph api", It fails for the keyword "facebook search"(which gives the results for the seperate keywords search like "facebook" and "search")).

Comment: Hi @ara! Happy to help! Could you please update your question to include the things you have tried already?